# Extracting class attribute from objects in non class array in python

Tags: python, class, save

I am trying to make a concatenated list of a class attribute from an array that contains class members but is not in the class itself.

```
class Direction:
def __init__(self, array, dir_name):
    self.array = array
    self.dir_name = dir_name
```

This enables me to create four class members, say L, R, U, D representing the directions and the array is an image array (openCV) and the dir_name is the letter, i.e. L.dir_name = 'L', same for 'R', 'U', 'D'.

I then generated a sequence of directions using a custom function and put them into an array called Arr_Seq, which is just an array, not a member of the class. So Arr_Seq contains some random sequence of LRUD directions which are the class objects with the two attributes

I want to save these sequences using an appropriate filename so to do so I need to generate a string that represents the sequence generated.

```
ns = 10
ArrSequence = [0]*ns

for i in range(ns):
    Arr_Seq = get_arrow_seq(6)
    if i<2:  
        ArrSequence[i] = np.hstack(Arr_Seq)  
    elif np.hstack(Arr_Seq) not in [ArrSequence]:
        ArrSequence[i] = np.hstack(Arr_Seq)  
    else:
        i = i-1    
    cv2.imwrite('ArrSeq_' + str(i) + '.png', ArrSequence[i])
```

This code above generates my image sequences but saves them like ArrSeq_0, ArrSeq_1, etc... not useful because I can't ID which file is which this way. I would like to be able to save the files as LLRUD, RRUDL, etc. so they are meaningful. I thought using the class would enable me to do this but I'm not sure how to extract the dir_name from elements in Arr_Seq, or how to then use that potential string to save the file appropriately.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What, you mean `ArrSequence[i].dir_name`?

Comment: When I do that I get the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dir_name' and same with Arr_Seq[i].dir_name.  Also I am not an advanced python user so I apologize if I am missing some steps here.

Comment: In that case you're going to have to explain what `get_arrow_seq` returns.

Comment: That's the function I've used to generate the sequence of arrows: `def get_arrow_seq(n):
    other_directions = [1,0,3,2]
    last_arrow = random.choice(range(4))
    arrows = [Arrow_Array[last_arrow]]

    this_arrow = other_directions[last_arrow]
    for i in range(n):
        while True:
            this_arrow = random.choice(range(4))
            if this_arrow != other_directions[last_arrow]:
                break
        arrows.append(Arrow_Array[this_arrow])
        last_arrow = this_arrow

    return arrows`

Comment: Also, Arrow_Array is just the array of arrows [L, R, U, D], the possible options from which to draw a random choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by assigning each direction to the class and then using the appropriate identifier to call the portion required.

```
class Direction:
def __init__(self, array, dir_name):
    self.array = array
    self.dir_name = dir_name      

L = Direction(L, 'L')
R = Direction(R, 'R')
U = Direction(U, 'U')
D = Direction(D, 'D')

Arrow_Array = [L.array, R.array, U.array, D.array]
```

and then using a (most likely inefficient) set of if statements to generate the letters that described the sequence:

```
num_seq = 2910
ArrSequence = [0]*num_seq

for i in range(num_seq):
    name = []    
    Arr_Seq = get_arrow_seq(6)
    for i in range(len(Arr_Seq)):     
        if (Arr_Seq[i] == L.array).all():
            name.append('L')
        elif (Arr_Seq[i] == R.array).all():
            name.append('R')
        elif (Arr_Seq[i] == U.array).all():
            name.append('U') 
        elif (Arr_Seq[i] == D.array).all():
            name.append('D')
        else:
            name.append(0)
    if i<2:  
        ArrSequence[i] = np.hstack(Arr_Seq) 

    elif np.hstack(Arr_Seq) not in [ArrSequence]:
        ArrSequence[i] = np.hstack(Arr_Seq)  

    else:
        i = i-1   

    cv2.imwrite(''.join(name) + '.png', ArrSequence[i])
```